# What is the dimension of the solution for Laplace's equation between two cylinders?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> Calculate the $\phi$, satisfying $\nabla^2 \phi=0$ between the two cylinders $r=a$, on which $\phi=0$, and $r=b>a$, on which $\phi=V$.

I calculate it and found the solution is $$\phi=\frac{V}{\log b-\log a}\log r-\frac{V}{\log b-\log a}\log a.$$

I am having trouble determining its dimension. Is it $2$ or $3$?

I use the following formula:
$v(r)=b\log r +c$, when $n=2$; $v(r)=\frac{b}{r^{n-2}}$, when $n\ge3$?
But neither seems right, since this is for a radially symmetric boundary condition. In this case, it is not radially symmetric.

Could someone kindly help me understand what the proper dimension is?

Comment: The solution is correct, in view of the symmetry along the vertical axis the problem is two-dimensional. In other words, $\phi$ does not depend on $z$ and, working in cylindrical coordinates, Laplace equation reduces to the two-dimensional one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is translationally symmetric along one spatial dimension, which means that it is effectively a two-dimensional problem. You have a weird understanding of what "the dimension of a potential" is - there's really no such concept. But if you define the dimension $n$ by matching a radially symmetric $\phi$ to either

- $v(r)=b\log r +c$ when $n=2$ or
- $v(r)=\frac{b}{r^{n-2}}$ when $n\ge3$

then it should be clear that the pattern that actually matches (exactly) is the first one, with $n=2$.

It's unclear why you think this is not a radially symmetric problem. If you rotate two coaxial cylinders about their common axis, do you get any observable change in the configuration?